# Unique ID and multiple classes with XPath

Tags: xslt, class, xpath, replace, unique

I'm using **XSLT** for displaying a `ul` menu containing `li` and `a`.

I want the following:

1. Find the first `li a` element and add the `.firstitem` class.
2. Find the last `li a` element and add the `.lastitem` class.
3. Find the active `li a` element and add the `.active` class.
4. Add an unique ID to each `li a` element. (I.e. URL friendly menu text as ID).

I've managed to make step 1-3 work. Except that when I try to add the classes, it actually replaces the other classes rather than adding to them.

Here's the code:

```
<li>
    <a>
        <!-- Add .firstitem class -->
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">firstitem</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Add .lastitem class -->
        <xsl:if test="postition() = count(//Page)">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">lastitem</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Add .active class -->
        <xsl:if test="@Active='True'">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Add link URL -->
        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyHref" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:attribute>

        <!-- Add link text -->
        <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

In realtity, the `a` element could contain all those three classes. But as is goes through the code, it replaces everything in the `class` attribute. How can I add the classes instead of replacing them?

And step number 4 on my list, is to get a unique ID, preferably based on `@MenuText`. I know there is a `replace()` function, but I can't get it to work and my editor says that `replace()` isn't a function.

The menu item text contains spaces, dashes and other symbols that are not valid for using in the `id` attribute. How can I replace those symbols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a>
       <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <!-- Add .firstitem class -->
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:text> firstitem</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <!-- Add .lastitem class -->
            <xsl:if test="postition() = count(//Page)">
                <xsl:text> lastitem</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>

            <!-- Add .active class -->
            <xsl:if test="@Active='True'">
                <xsl:text> active</xsl:text>
           </xsl:if>
       </xsl:attribute>

        <!-- Add link URL -->
        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyHref" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:attribute>

        <!-- Add link text -->
        <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </a>
```

`replace()` is an XSLT2.0 function. When using XSLT1.0 you need a [custom template](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025173545/http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx) to do most string manipulations.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't knew this myself. So obvious when I see it now :P

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding this to Martijn Laarman's answer, which covers your requirements 1-3 and has my vote:

To remove everything except a certain range of characters from  a string with XSLT 1.0 (your 4th requirement), do the following.

```
<!-- declare at top level -->
<xsl:variable 
  name="validRange" 
  select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789' 
/>

<!-- later, within a template… -->
<xsl:attribute name="id">
  <xsl:value-of select="
    concat(
      'id_',
      translate(
        @MenuText, 
        translate(@MenuText, $validRange, ''),
        ''
      )
    )
  " />
</xsl:attribute>
```

The inner `translate()` removes any valid character from `@MenuText`, leaving only the invalid ones. These are fed to the outer `translate()`, which now can remove all *invalid* chars from the `@MenuText`, whatever they might be in this instance. Only the valid chars remain.

You can make a function out of it:

```
<xsl:template name="HtmlIdFromString">
  <xsl:param name="input" select="''" />
  <xsl:value-of select="
    concat('id_', translate( $input, translate($input, $validRange, ''), ''))
  " />
</xsl:template>
```

and call it like this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="id">
  <xsl:call-template name="HtmlIdFromString">
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="@MenuText" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use</strike>

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to copy all existing attributes.

The replace() function is only supported in xslt 2.0 but i found [this workaround](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025173545/http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx) for xslt 1.0.

Comment: Okay, i missed that the issue was only concerning the class attribute; i thought other attributes went missing.